# Is there a way to run a command on keyboard press in vscode extension?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, package.json, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to create a VS Code extension that should run a command when the user presses a certain keybinding.

For example: When the user presses `Ctrl+Shift+E` a popup window should appear in VS Code.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: There is a documentation on this. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

Comment: Yes, you can set a keybinding in the extension's `package.json` to run a command.